# File I/O using plain TeX commands

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I was following page 216 of Knuth, but cannot get the following code to run.  The error message is:

```
! Emergency stop.
<read 1> 

l.12 \read\fid to\temp

*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
```

I might mention that I cannot find `\openin` in the log file at all.

```
\begin{filecontents}{address.txt}
test
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{article}
\tracingmacros=1
\newread\fid
\begin{document}
\the\fid

\openin\fid={address.txt}
\read\fid to\temp
\closein\fid
\temp
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused: you say you're following The TeXbook, but show a LaTeX document… For all I know, LaTeX might have redefined some plain TeX macros, or even primitives. Is this reproducible with a plain TeX file?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - most TeX macros still work.  Whether LaTeX disables \openin is sort of what I am trying to find out, I also tried using the plain package.

Comment: For contrast, can you give a plain TeX version that works, and a LaTeX version that doesn't? It would make it easier to understand the question (at least for me). (Because even when I try to turn your example into a `plain` equivalent, it tries to read from the terminal, and whatever I type in the terminal ends up in the final output dvi file.)

Comment: You've got the syntax of `\openin` wrong: `\openin\fid=address.txt %` with no braces. I also agree that this is quite confusing as-written ([tag:plain-tex] is for things that _only_ apply to plain: perhaps you mean [tag:tex-core]?)

Comment: Yes I figured out the same: `\openin\fid=address.txt` works if you have a file named `address.txt`. With the brace it tries to read from the terminal, which is rather confusing.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The braces are part of the file name (except for LuaTeX). The file does not exist and TeX tries the terminal as file recovery before throwing an error in the case that TeX cannot read from the terminal.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for that explanation. I've been flipping through the TeX program and it has an impressive amount of error-recovery, going to great lengths. Much of TeX's “error recovery” made a lot of sense when jobs were slow and rerunning TeX would have been prohibitively expensive, but these days, relative to the typical user interactions with other programs, it actually gets annoying sometimes… throwing a clear and descriptive error that cannot be recovered from would probably be better, in cases like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax with curly braces in

```
\openin\fid={address.txt}
```

is only supported by LuaTeX.
The syntax for other TeX engines:

```
\openin\fid=address.txt
```

Where the file name can be ended by a space or `\relax`.
Spaces in file names are supported in some cases with quotes:

```
\openin\fid="address.txt"
```

(But that means, that quotes in file names are not supported ...)

Comment: As Windows forbids `"` anyway, for safe cross-platform work it's ruled out anyway ... (this is the thinking in `l3file`, for example).

Comment: Heiko is this still the case? Looks like pdflatex now also supports the braces.